# Обработать текст страницы

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть задача, изменить все буквы(слова) `А` на `Б` на всей html загруженной страницы, из-под custom script

Самое банальное, что приходит в голову(не думая):

```js
let x = $('body').html();
x = x.split('A').join('B');
$('body').html(x);
```

Ну, или тоже самое, но перебором элементов...

Дак вот, суть вопроса, как лучше это сделать - со стороны оптимизации и\или работы с большими строками..?

Т.е. банально регексп нарисовать и_к_нему\или переборщик элементов `$('[value],:contains("A")')...` например, или есть варианты полудшэ-е?

**Суть** не в том, чтобы не изменять например - имя класса, а в том, как со стороны оптимизации сделать всё гораздо быстрее и смышленнее чем перебором\работой со строкой, может есть какие-то ТРЮКИ\идеи, а не эти палка с камнем

Comment: В общем, `x = x.replace(/А/g, 'Б');`. Но так как у вас HTML, возможно, тут стоит подумать об использовании парсера HTML, чтобы замена происходила только в текстовых элементах.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew пиши развернутый ответ, не стесняйся :)

Comment: Пока что неясно, нужно ли заменять только в текстовых элементах, или же в тегах/атрибутах тоже.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew видимый текст, например "Вырезать всех вадимов на стаковерфлоу"

Comment: Напрашивается вопрос... а какую задачу решаете, которая требует десятки миллионов замен за секунду, чтобы думать про оптимизацию? Или просто интересно, какой вариант будет работать быстрее?) Тогда напрашивается другой вопрос: Какая разница, 50 миллисекунд, или 100 )

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME напрашивается вопрос зачем удалять ответы..) Хочется: быстрее + чтоб меньше оперативы жрало + меньше цп жрало + магия. Ну и уже как ps 50 или 100

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME верни ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let textNodes = (
  [...document.querySelectorAll("body, body *")] // body, и все HTML-элементы внутри него
  .map(e => [...e.childNodes])         // подменить их на их дочерние узлы
  .flat()
  .filter(node => node.nodeType === 3) // взять только текстовые
);

textNodes.forEach(txt => txt.textContent = txt.textContent.replace(/A/g, "B"));
```

```css
.MAMA { color: red; }
```

```html
<body>
  AAA
  <div class="MAMA">
    MAMA
    <div>EEE AAA</div>  
    LALA
  </div>
  AAA
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Если я не ошибаюсь, в данной задаче эффективность не единственное, что нужно принять во внимание. Задумайтесь ещё и над такими моментами.

1. Может ли замена испортить разметку и функциональность. В вашем варианте замена затронет всё — имена тегов и атрибуты, тексты стилей и скриптов.
2. Полная перезапись всего html полностью заменит все DOM элементы. Если в `head` были какие-то скрипты и они повесили на элементы обработчики событий, всё это будет утрачено.

Если вам нужно наиболее аккуратно пройтись только по текстовым узлам и совершить замену в них, единственный вариант — выбирать эти текстовые узлы и проходиться по ним, поэтому от работы с DOM и от цикла с заменой вы вряд ли сможете уклониться. Один из вариантов — использовать XPath, с ним легче вычленить только текстовые узлы:

```js
function replaceInTextNodes(pattern, replacement, parentNode = document.body) {

  const xpathTextNodes = './descendant-or-self::*[not(self::script or self::style)]/text()';

  const textNodes = document.evaluate(
    xpathTextNodes, parentNode, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null
  );

  for (let i = 0, node; (node = textNodes.snapshotItem(i)); i++) {
    node.textContent = node.textContent.replace(pattern, replacement);
  }
}
```

Comment: Можешь фор конструкцию убрать, чтобы совместимость была с `document.body.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted'`?

Comment: Простите, не понимаю. Перефразируйте, пожалуйста, или опишите детальнее.

Comment: Я имею ввиду, что скрипт не адаптирован к динамическим объедкам, например если сообщение в вк отправить, то А на Б не сменится, нужен лисанер, я его дам, скрипта адаптацию я не даммм

Comment: Если вам нужно применить этот подход только к добавляемому элементу, достаточно заменить аргумент `document.body` в вызове `document.evaluate()` на этот самый добавляемый элемент, это сузит контекст замены. Но цикл всё равно может быть нужен, потому что в добавляемом элементе может быть несколько текстовых узлов.

Comment: Отредактировал ответ, теперь это общая функция, которой можно задавать обрабатываемый элемент (по умолчанию всё тело страницы), шаблон и замену.